# how to execute several functions with same arguments js

Tags: javascript

I have an object and 3 methods, now my code to execute it looks like this:

```
var cmpAmount = 50,
    addLessAmount = 6,
    addMoreAmount = 14;
priceChanger.changeSmallPrice(cmpAmount, addLessAmount, addMoreAmount);
priceChanger.changeBigPrice(cmpAmount, addLessAmount, addMoreAmount);
priceChanger.changeTooltipPrice(cmpAmount, addLessAmount, addMoreAmount);
```

so, if arguments are the same how to execute it three with sending them the parameters.
I mean how to change my code to make it less.

Comment: May be there is something wrong in your code, I guess not following the DRY principle.

Comment: `priceChanger.changeAllPrices`?

Comment: How about creating one function in your object that executes the other three, just pass the arguments array along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be best to make a method "changeAllPrices(cmpAmount, addLessAmount, addMoreAmount)"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using a object to store all properties :

```
var args = {cmpAmount:50,addLessAmount: 6, addMoreAmount: 14};

priceChanger.changeSmallPrice(args);
priceChanger.changeBigPrice(args);
priceChanger.changeTooltipPrice(args);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple helper function, such as the one below, to call each function with an array of arguments. I believe some javascript libraries include a similar composition function called `composeArgs`

```
function execute(fns, args) {
   for(var i = 0; i < fns.length; i++) {
       fns[i].apply(this, args);
   }
}
```

Then call execute

```
var cmpAmount = 50,
    addLessAmount = 6,
    addMoreAmount = 14;

execute([priceChanger.changeSmallPrice, priceChanger.changeBigPrice, priceChanger.changeTooltipPrice], 
        [cmpAmount, addLessAmount, addMoreAmount]);
```